# Using xml_replace leaves behind some formatting

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I am trying to replace some nodes of an XML document with text using the `xml2` library in R. In the example below I'm trying to turn all the "name" nodes into text, but the final result still has the "<" and "/>" around the text.

```
library(xml2)
x <- read_xml(
  "<scenario>
  <event>
  <dataProbeEvent>
  <name>LogSurvResHigh</name>
  </dataProbeEvent>
  </event>
  <event>
  <accumulateEvent>
  <name>SetSurvOut</name>
  </accumulateEvent>
  </event>
  </scenario>")
x
> {xml_document}
<scenario>
[1] <event>\n  <dataProbeEvent>\n    <name>LogSurvResHigh</name>\n  </dataProbeEvent>\n ...
[2] <event>\n  <accumulateEvent>\n    <name>SetSurvOut</name>\n  </accumulateEvent>\n</ ...
namerefs <- xml_find_all(x, './/name')
replacements = namerefs %>%xml_text()
xml_replace(namerefs, replacements)
> {xml_document}
<scenario>
[1] <event>\n  <dataProbeEvent>\n    <LogSurvResHigh/>\n  </dataProbeEvent>\n</event>
[2] <event>\n  <accumulateEvent>\n    <SetSurvOut/>\n  </accumulateEvent>\n</event>
```

What I want it to look like is:

```
> {xml_document}
<scenario>
[1] <event>\n  <dataProbeEvent>\n    LogSurvResHigh\n  </dataProbeEvent>\n</event>
[2] <event>\n  <accumulateEvent>\n    SetSurvOut\n  </accumulateEvent>\n</event>
```

Comment: What would be the expected output? According to [xml specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) what you currently get is an empty-element tag, such as <line-break />

Comment: Thanks for expected output : so this should only be text, and not anymore valid `xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the following:-

```
x <- as.character(x)
x_sub <- gsub("<name[^>]*>|<\\/name>","",x)
x <- read_xml(x_sub)
x

{xml_document}
<scenario>
[1] <event>\n  <dataProbeEvent>\n      LogSurvResHigh\n  </dataProbeEvent>\n</event>
[2] <event>\n  <accumulateEvent>\n      SetSurvOut\n    </accumulateEvent>\n</event>
```

This will remove `ref-type="bibr" rid="CR8"` kind of attributes from the `name` node.

Answer (score 0):

XML documents are a type of nested data type a lot like a list in R. If you prune a node then all of the information in that node is lost. I find it generally easier to convert it to a flat data type (like a character vector) and then remove the information that isn't desired. It can then be converted back to XML if desired.

The alternative would be to use XML to locate the parent node that you want and then use xml_text to extract the text. But I believe this drops all newline characters.

```
x_char <- as.character(x)
x_noname <- gsub("<name>|<\\/name>","",x_char)
x_noname

x_noname <- read_xml(x_noname)
x_noname
# {xml_document}
# <scenario>
#   [1] <event>\n  <dataProbeEvent>\n      LogSurvResHigh\n    </dataProbeEvent>\n</event>
#   [2] <event>\n  <accumulateEvent>\n      SetSurvOut\n    </accumulateEvent>\n</event>
```

Comment: That almost works, but sometimes there's additional information, for example `<name ref-type="bibr" rid="CR8">2</name>` and this can be of varying length, so I need something like `<name.*>` in the pattern to match on, but that also deletes the `2` in this example which I want to keep.